# SQL SERVER Full Text Search - replacing text in a contains statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to do a string replacement inside of a `CONTAINS` statement?  I have my code set up like so :

```
INSERT @searchfilter (productid, variantID)
SELECT p.ProductID, pv.VariantID from dbo.Product p with(NOLOCK)
    JOIN dbo.ProductVariant pv with(NOLOCK) on p.ProductID = pv.ProductID 
    JOIN dbo.ProductStore ps with(NOLOCK) on p.ProductID = ps.ProductID and ps.StoreID = @storeID
    WHERE CONTAINS((dbo.vibe_GetValidSearchString(p.Name, @storeID), p.SKU), @NameField)
```

I've got an error though on the `CONTAINS` statement and I'm unable to get it to compile.  The error is `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected.`

I've also tried changing the function in the `WHERE` to be

```
 ... WHERE CONTAINS((REPLACE(p.Name,'-',''), p.SKU), @NameField)
```

but it's giving the same error.  Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: somerhing is missing between `((` in the where clause??

Comment: @Hiten004 No - When I have `WHERE CONTAINS((p.Name, p.Description, p.SKU), @NameField)` It works great, but when I try to alter the column, it throws an error

Comment: i do not think that you can put funcation within  `CONTAINS` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE CONTAINS(
               (dbo.vibe_GetValidSearchString(p.Name, @storeID), p.SKU)
               , @NameField
               )
```

Look at the second line

```
               (dbo.vibe_GetValidSearchString(p.Name, @storeID), p.SKU)
```

Maybe an operand is missing,  what shall you do with the result of `vibe_GetValidSearchString` and  `p.SKU`  ?

Anyway, instead of `CONTAINS` you could use `LIKE` operator (you hav to concatenate `%` with text)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it like this, because the first argument of `CONTAINS` is a column name that is not normally passed as a string.

However, you could work around it using [EXEC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx). Something along the lines of:

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE CONTAINS(' + dbo.vibe_GetValidSearchString(p.Name, @storeID), p.SKU) ', ''' + @NameField + ''')'
EXEC (@SQL)
```